# C# split string and assign it to different integer variables

Tags: c#

I have a string variable something like this - 123456. I would like to split  them and assign to int a = 12 and int b = 3456.
How can we do this in C#?

Comment: It depends. Would it be always the first 2 characters to the first int and the rest to the second? Then use `Substring`

Comment: Split based on what? It's easy to use `Substring(0,2)` and `Substring(2)` and cast to int, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Yes @ZoharPeled, this works. Thanks

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Just a point of pedantry.  You cannot _cast_ the string to int, but you can _parse_ it.  I think it's important to use proper terminology, especially when the terms used have different meaning.  As you know, casting and parsing are different things.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Correct. Parse is indeed the correct term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution based on the comments:

```
string x = "123456";
int a = int.Parse(x.Substring(0,2));
int b = int.Parse(x.Substring(2));
```

Comment: This works, but I run the Main program, I am getting an exception - {"Index and length must refer to a location within the string.\r\nParameter name: length"}, Is this because of Substring? Pls help

Comment: Yes, if your string is shorter than 2 chars you will get that exception on the first Substring, if it's shorter than 3 chars you will get it on the second one, but the parameter name would be `index`.